# How to parse JSON data with custom object names?

Tags: json, typescript

I want to parse a JSON with Typescript, where object names can vary and I have no way to know them all. For example:

```
{
     "planets": {

       "Alderaan": {

        "available_items": {

            "Cinamone": {

                "available": 74,

                "buy_price": 6,

                "sell_price": 6

            },

            "Dwimeryt": {

                "available": 42,

                "buy_price": 12,

                "sell_price": 11

            }
       }
    }
}
```

Where there can be many planets with different names.

I figured out that in order to parse JSON object successfully, we need to have corrent variable names, so for example that works:

```
interface MyObj {
     x: number;
     y: number:
}

let json_string = `{
        "x": 5,
         "y": 12
    }`;
  let test: MyObj = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

But if we change variable name in interface from "x" to lets say "xx" it becomes undefined after parsing. That creates seemingly unsolvable problem if we cant know all of the JSON object names, because I cant create an interface withh all of the planet names. Am I missing something? How would you parse a JSON I have posted?

Comment: If there is no consistency in the structure, what is the point of using an interface?  The JSON is parsed just fine; the problem is trying to shoe-horn it into an interface that it doesn't correspond to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any influence on the JSON itself? To me it seems that it is not the best  way to use JSON. If I would try to design this, your JSON would look more like this:

```
{
     "planets": [
     {
        "name": "Alderaan",

        "available_items": [

        {
            "name": "Cinamone",

            "available": 74,

            "buy_price": 6,

            "sell_price": 6

         }, {
            "name": "Dwimeryt",

            "available": 42,

            "buy_price": 12,

            "sell_price": 11
         }]

    }]
}
```

This way you would always know the name of the fields and also their types. I do not think that this could be achieved easily with the current JSON format.